# Office 2010 UI in Visual Studio 2008/2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, ribbon, office-2010

Is there a futurepack or something like that for Visual Studio 2010, where i could use new ribbon UI of Microsoft Office 2010 in MFC. I know that Microsoft released FuturePack for VS 2008 to develop apps in C++/MFC with Office 2007 RibbonUI. I have searched for that, but found only in managed code (.NET) in C# for WPF. But i would like to develop using MFC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 now includes a [Ribbon Designer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/10/01/ribbon-designer.aspx) as part of the application creation wizard.

Comment: But that includes only Windows 7 and Office 2007 styles. What about Office 2010 styles or ribbons???